# I put 2-stroke fuel in my 4-stroke mower and now it won't start

Tags: lawn-mower

My first time doing the lawn. Trying to help. Now I can't get it to start.

Comment: That's the less dangerous way.  **Don't** do it the other way 'round, or you'll be buying yourself a new chainsaw/weedwacker.

Comment: More likely the mixed fuel is old and has lost its volatility. Remove the fuel from the mower and add fresh gas.

Comment: Was the gasoline new or had it sat all winter?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because small engine repair should have been migrated to [mechanics.se].

Answer (score 5):

Remove the air filter and spray a small blast of starting fluid into the carburetor. It should run for a second or two. If it does then the problem is the gas is most likely old/bad. If it doesn't run for even a split second then you're not getting any spark which means you have an ignition problem which is most likely a fouled spark plug.

Answer (score 3):

I've burned off old gas and even 2-cycle in a 4-cycle motor. Some tips I've found to help with this

1. Buy some pre-mix stabilized 4-cycle gas (sold in home improvement stores next to the 2-cycle pre-mix). It typically has better detergents than pump gas and can help you get a bad motor started again
2. Clean your spark plug. Take it off the mower and clean it with a wire brush. This sometimes helps to get a better spark going
3. If you have a push primer, try doing a LOT of priming to get the newer gas into the chamber. Otherwise, just keep trying to crank it.

Answer (score 2):

Not likely the problem ; it has a little oil in the same gasoline ; you may see a little blue smoke when it is running. When I have been short on gas , I have added at least 50 % 2 cycle gas to my 4 cycle mower to finish the lawn.

Comment: What could be the reason why it will not start?

Comment: Fouled spark plug? The oil burns with a lot more carbon. Did it run at all though? If it never started, then it's probably something else.

Comment: This might help if you'relooking for more general starting issues: https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/109999/difficult-to-start-a-four-stroke-mower-when-cold-how-to-diagnose-the-problem?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

It might not have started anyway this season. Petrol left in the carb. degrades and crystallises, so even with the right fuel, it won't start.

If, however, all the fuel from last year was drained out/ run till dry, it'll be the oil in the two-stroke petrol oiling up the spark plug. Which will have to be removed, cleaned and dried. Two stroke mix carefully drained, new petrol put in, and if possible, drain not just the tank but the carb also. With extremem care!